# Custom ggplot legend by group

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, legend

I want to create a graph like below but with a custom legend by group. I have two samples names A and B and a target (Y) associated. what I want is to group the legend with one side :
**sample A** : true vs obs
and other side
**sample B** : true vs obs
with the corresponding shape and color.
Below, this is what I already had.

```
library(ggplot2)
sites = rep(seq(0.55,0.58,0.01), times = 4)
sites = sort(sites)

org = rep(c("Y_A", "Y_A_obs", "Y_b", "Y_b_obs"), times = 4)
values = rnorm(16)

df = data.frame(sites = sites, origine = org, values = values)

ggplot(df, aes(x=sites, y=values, color=origine)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=origine, color=origine), size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(0, 15, 2, 17))+
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue", "purple", "red", "orange"))
```

[image]

And this is what I want:
[image]

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of the `ggnewscale` package which allows for multiple scales and legends for the same aesthetic(s). Drawback of this method is that it doubles the lines of code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

set.seed(123)

sites = rep(seq(0.55,0.58,0.01), times = 4)
sites = sort(sites)

org = rep(c("Y_A", "Y_A_obs", "Y_b", "Y_b_obs"), times = 4)
values = rnorm(16)

df = data.frame(sites = sites, origine = org, values = values)

ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = subset(df, grepl("^Y_A", org)), aes(x=sites, y=values, shape=origine, color=origine), size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "A", values=c(Y_A = 0, Y_A_obs = 15), 
                     labels=c(Y_A = "y_true", Y_A_obs = "y_pred"), 
                     guide = guide_legend(order = 1))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "A", 
                     values=c(Y_A = "blue", Y_A_obs = "purple"), 
                     labels=c(Y_A = "y_true", Y_A_obs = "y_pred"), 
                     guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  new_scale_color() +
  new_scale("shape") +
  geom_point(data = subset(df, grepl("^Y_b", org)), aes(x=sites, y=values, shape=origine, color=origine), size=3)+
  scale_shape_manual(name = "B", 
                     values=c(Y_b = 2, Y_b_obs = 17), 
                     labels=c(Y_b = "y_true", Y_b_obs = "y_pred"), 
                     guide = guide_legend(order = 2))+
  scale_color_manual(name = "B", 
                     values=c(Y_b = "red", Y_b_obs = "orange"), 
                     labels=c(Y_b = "y_true", Y_b_obs = "y_pred"),
                     guide = guide_legend(order = 2))
```

[image]